# Gerrit: attaching previous users with new ldap users

Tags: ldap, gerrit

We were previously using openid for authentication in gerrit. Now we want to use ldap for this. i want new ldap userid's to be attached with their previous ones. How can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

There is a ticket raised for what you ask about: 
https://code.google.com/p/gerrit/issues/detail?id=567

> The SQL script on the wiki should be able to merge any two accounts,
>   LDAP or OpenID, it doesn't care.  Though after merging two LDAP
>   accounts you may need to go and delete the old "gerrit:%s"
>   account_external_id record.
>
> Anyway, we really want this in the web UI so its either self-service
>   for an OpenID user, or is available to a site administrator so they
>   can help out a user who cannot do the merge on their own.  Doing it by
>   SQL update is not fun, and will become impossible when we are running
>   on a NoSQL system.

The requested feature seems to be not implemented yet, however the quotation author mentions something about "script on the wiki", but I was unable to find it.. maybe someone else will have better luck.